# How to cope with runaway Flash plugin in Google Chrome browser?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, flash, cpu-usage

I'm using Google Chrome for Linux, version 5.0.307.11 (Official Build 39572) beta with the Linux Flash plugin version  10.0 r32.  Quite often, the Flash plugin goes wild and pegs the CPU with about 95% usage.  Laptop gets hot, battery drains.  I can diagnose the problem with Chrome's little process monitor (shift-Esc), and I can even kill the plugin, but then when I actually want to use Flash on a page, I can't find a way to restart the plugin; I have to exit and restart Chrome, which with 30 tabs open is a huge hit.

Does anyone know what causes this problem?

Does anyone have a better workaround (or heaven forfend, a fix)?

[I struck out both with search and with Google's help site for Chrome.]

Comment: Stable flash on linux? Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I'm on a Windows box)

I was able to restart the process by

1. Opening Chrome's task manager
2. Ending the Flash plugin's process
3. Refreshing a page with Flash content.

Comment: Brilliant this works exactly perfectly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On my box with ubuntu 9.10 running google chrome the flash plugin doesnt actually start until I load a page with flash(I believe that is the default, and if it isnt I do not know how I changed it) and if I kill the program refreshing/navigating to a page with flash will start it again.